# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Double]'

Tags: xcode

I already read all the answers in stack overflow for similar problems, and tried the suggestions for them, but cannot solve this error (Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String:Double]'), which occurs on line "if let jsonDictionary = json {". Please help! Thanks in advance!

```
func getPrice(cprCcy: String, ccy: String){
    if let url = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=" + cprCcy + "&tsyms=" + ccy){
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                print ("connected to the url")
                if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? [String:Double]{
                    if let jsonDictionary = json {
                        if let price = jsonDictionary[ccy] {
                            print(price)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                print("wrong =(")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: I just copied your function into my project and its working fine. It's not giving any error. I'm using Xcode 10.1.

Comment: I have 10.2 (it was updated automatically, without me asking). I will see if I can go back to 10.1. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found a simple solution:

replaced this part :

```
if let jsonDictionary = json {
   if let price = jsonDictionary[ccy] {
      print(price)
   }
}
```

by this:

```
if let price = json[ccy] {
   print(price)
}
```

that is, just eliminated the line that was causing me problems and moved the variable to the next line.